# what do we gain by using a weak topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space.

my question is a bit general but I think it is important: what do we gain by using a weak topology instead of a strong topology in $X$.
And what do we lose?

Comment: Sequential compactness!

Comment: Your set of continuous functions depends on the topology.  Changing the topology may remove problematic functions.

Comment: In most cases, you make the topology weaker to make a set that wasn't compact before (such as a norm-closed ball in an infinite dimensional Banach space) become compact. This enables you to extract a limit from an approximating sequence of solutions to a problem. The issue is that you then need to go back and ensure that your limit actually solves the problem, which is sometimes difficult.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The weak topology has the same *linear* continuous functions though.

Answer (score 2):

One answer: compactness arguments can be easier in the weak topology than in the strong.

Comment: Basically, because the fewer open sets you have, the fewer open covers, and so the easier it becomes to be compact. In the topology with only two open sets (an extreme case) *all* subsets becomes compact. The weak topology is chosen so that we keep the same continuous functionals but a lot fewer open sets and a lot more compact sets.